# x-editable on button, how to edit specific comment?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, x-editable

I have added x-editable comment to edit on button, but i have no idea how edit button can find out which object edit?

```
<% commentable.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <div class="well">
      <a  href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="<%= comment.id %>"
          style="border:none; color:black; text-decoration: none !important;cursor: default;"
          id="edit-comment"
          data-model="comment"
          data-name="content"
          data-type="text"
          method="put"
          data-toggle="manual"
          data-url="<%= comment_path(comment) %>">
          <%= comment.content %>
      </a>
      <div class="btn btn-default" id="edit-button" style="float:right;"> 
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"> Edit </span> 
      </div>
    </div>
```

My Js:

```
/* X-Editable*/
$(function() {
  $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
  return $("[data-xeditable=true]").each(function() {
    return $(this).editable({
      ajaxOptions: {
        type: "PUT",
        dataType: "json"
      },
      params: function(params) {
        var railsParams;
        railsParams = {};
        railsParams[$(this).data("model")] = {};
        railsParams[$(this).data("model")][params.name] = params.value;
        return railsParams;
      }
    });
  });
});
$(function() {
$('#edit-button').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#edit-comment').editable('toggle');
});
});
```

and result is: When i click on edit button i can edit 1st comment which has id: "edit-comment". Problem start when i create next comment in the loop and this comment have the same id :) and how second edit button on trigger can know which comment (object) edit?

Comment: how can it have same `id` ? If it's running inside the loop then it must be different no ?

Comment: yes...so i was trying loop and use classes...but on click every edit button only last comment activate editable...how can i find parent using $(this)? any help?

Answer (score 1):

ok ive got solution. "Find parent to button and then find iterate object with class edit-comment and on that element use toggle"

When i understand this logic i needed only use properly syntax so:

```
$(function() {  
    $('.edit-button').click(function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      $(this).parent().find(".edit-comment").editable('toggle');
    });
});
```